# Reactjs socks does not apply down mode to rendered output

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design

I started to use React Socks library to make my responsive design easier to manage. Problem is that althought desktop version is being switched off when i narrow browsers window the mobile version [ indicated by Mobile version#1 text ] is visible despite the screen size. I used Google Chrome's as well as Microsoft Edge's dev tools to check if i am wrong about pixels but no. Only desktop version works properly and mobile version is visible despite screen width changes. I widen it to maximum and the Mobile version#1 component is all the time visible. Can you help me and point out what am I missing?

```
import React from "react";   
import { setDefaultBreakpoints } from 'react-socks';
import Breakpoint, { BreakpointProvider } from 'react-socks';   

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    setDefaultBreakpoints([
      { desktop: 1025 }
    ]);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <BreakpointProvider>
        <Breakpoint desktop down>
          <div style={{padding: "10px", border:"1px solid red"}}>
            Mobile version#1
          </div>
        </Breakpoint>

        <br/>
        <br/>

        <Breakpoint desktop up>
          <div style={{padding: "10px", border:"1px solid red"}}>
            Desktop version#1
          </div>
        </Breakpoint>
      </BreakpointProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me.

You have not closed `</BreakpointProvider>` in your code.

Try below code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { setDefaultBreakpoints } from 'react-socks';
import Breakpoint, { BreakpointProvider } from 'react-socks';   

class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
    setDefaultBreakpoints([
      { desktop: 1025 }
    ]);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <BreakpointProvider>
        <Breakpoint desktop down>
          <div style={{padding: "10px", border:"1px solid red"}}>
            Mobile version#1
          </div>
        </Breakpoint>

        <br/>
        <br/>

        <Breakpoint desktop up>
          <div style={{padding: "10px", border:"1px solid red"}}>
            Desktop version#1
          </div>
        </Breakpoint>
      </BreakpointProvider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Happy coding!!!

Comment: For me still it is not working. For the moment I will have to rely on @media css element. Thank you for now.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging by looking at what `useCurrentBreakpointName()` returns might be helpful.

I had to treat it like a range of valid widths, rather than like a line that gets crossed, and use the `only` modifier, instead. Something like this is working for me:

```
setDefaultBreakpoints([{ mobile: 0 }, { desktop: 1025 }]);

<Breakpoint mobile only>
  Shows up below 1025 and does not show up above.
</Breakpoint>

<Breakpoint desktop only>
  Shows up above 1025 and does not show up below.
</Breakpoint>
```

This is using `"react-socks": "^2.1.0"`.